# Reader field and group name

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

Can a reader field contains group name ?

If yes, where does Domino check the existance of that group and the members of ?

I didn't find any official documentation about a group inserted into a document reader field, but I saw a reference to it into [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467842/notes-acl-reader-level-and-readers-authors-fields/21468465#21468465)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This document](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_RESTRICTING_ACCESS_TO_SPECIFIC_DOCUMENTS_USING_A_READERS_FIELD.html?lang=en) from the designer- help answers your question:

> A Readers field may contain Notes® usernames, groups defined in the Domino® Directory provided those groups are of the "Access control list" or "Multipurpose" type, or roles defined in the database Access Control List

But the answer is incomplete. Reader- Fields can also contain Wildcard- entries like `*/YourOrganization`.

And the users don't need to be defined in the domino directory, they can also be in a directory that is known to the server via a Directory Assistance Database as long as the property `Trusted for Credentials` is enabled for the directories configured there. For groups to be effective the property `Group authorization` has to be set to `yes` in additon.